# Get global resource vale for the Model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model like this..

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have my `Resources.resx` file in the **App_GlobalResources** folder.
But when I try to access the `Username` value from the resource file it says..

```
Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 
'Resources.Resources' is not public or does not contain a public static 
string property with the name 'Username'
```

But I have a value for Username there. How can I retrieve the value from the Global Resources file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you view the resx file in VS, there's an option for the 'Access Modifier' (should appear under the tabs).  This is set to internal by default, you'll need to change it to Public.

Comment: I changed that. This only happend when I use global resource files.
When I have a different application layer for models it works

Answer (score 0):

I have a MVC soloution w Entity Framework.
There is no multilingual or anything set up, but I do have a Properties.Resources.resx so I can quickly match UI keywords to the customer's terminology. (It is public and all that jazz)

I get the same error; it was in connection with

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentTypeId, ...
```

I had a resource: 'DocumentTypeID' and one of the classes in my mvc model has a property: 'DocumentTypeId'.

The solution was to change the name of the resource 'DocumentTypeID' to 'DocumentTypeId'.

Apparently when you have resources and properties of the same name, they have to match case-wise.

Answer (score -1):

Change the access modifier to `public` to your resource file class in `Resources.Designer.cs` file. Default is `internal`

```
public class Resources{

}
```

Also ensure you have a valid entry in the file for `Username`

```
public static string Username{
 get{
   return ResourceManager.GetString("Username", resourceCulture);
  }
}
```

Comment: It still get have the issu

Comment: hey @Murali I have sent u request in LinkedIn plz accept